# Auto generate header files for a C source file in an IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-cdt, header-files

I am trying to use Eclipse and NetBeans for programming in C (not C++). Is there a feature/plugin for them which automatically keeps the source and header files in sync?

As in, when I implement a function in the source file, does it automatically insert the correct lines in the header file?

I did look at solutions like lzz, but they are not what I am looking for.

Comment: These are usually implemented via macros. I have never come across IDE features per se, though I'd love to know more.

Comment: I noticed you didn't tag the question as eclipse-cdt.  If you're using eclipse with C you should install it http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 10):

Eclipse CDT allows you to write a prototype in the header file, and automatically add it to the C file.

**Instructions**

1. Add function prototype to .h file void foobar()
2. Select the function name "foobar" (try double clicking)
3. In the toolbar click Source -> Implement Method
4. Wizard it up

Thats probably the best you're gonna get out of the box

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Eclipse 3.6.2 (CDT version 7.0.1.201009241320). I get asked to choose a method to implement from a list ... an empty list! Did you really mean C, and not C++? Because only C++ uses the terminology "method".

Answer (score 0):

Agree with approach proposed by Ryu. In C, I would not automatically create declarations in headers. This should be an explicit action making public some symbol from the C module.

However if declaration/implementation are already setup and you want to modify any of them, I imagine that with Eclipse you may want to use [Toggle Function Definition](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_toggle.htm) in a possible workflow where you copy in clipboard intermediate toggling results and paste them later over the changed declaration or implementation declaration.

Also use rename refactoring intensively when you change things.